# How to remove lines with fewer than five fields in a file

Tags: awk, sed

I have a file (example below). 
Some lines have five fields, where the fifth field is a number. 
But a few lines in the file have only four fields.

How can we remove these lines with only four fields? 
They are not aligned by columns.

```
delay  from  threshold/temp/atp/CK   rx/tx/sx/C14/CLR/DQ  5.0
delay  from  threshold2   rx/C10/CLR  7.0
delay  to    threshold10  rx10  3.0
delay  from  min/max/values/atp  tx/rx/mx/T13/CLR
delay  to  min5/atp2  tx/mx/P11/CTR
```

In the above example
I want to remove the fourth and fifth lines.

I tried `awk -F\| '$5~/\w/' file`, but it did not help.

Comment: Specifying a file separator of '|' (assuming it was quoted) means all your lines have one field, because there are no separators. And if $5 contains a decimal point, it does not match \w (a word). But that test is reversed anyway.

Comment: Also `\w` is a non-POSIX extension shorthand for `[[:alnum:]_]` that'll only work in some awks.

Answer (score 3):

`awk '$5~/\w/'` does work for me. It prints all lines where the fifth column matches the regex `\w` aka `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Make sure to specify the correct delimiter with the `-F` option.

`awk 'NF>4'` expresses your intention more clearly. It prints all lines whose Number of Fields is greater than 4.

Comment: Thanks  a lot,  awk 'NF>4' this works for my requirement